# How to Connect Laravel 5 to Android?

Tags: php, android, laravel

Im a bit curious on how to connect Laravel as a Web Service to Android. Im currently Connecting Native php to android. and It is a success in the connection. 
but sadly i made my laravel codes but keeps failing. i think i need an answer on how to make laravel web services for android

Here are my Android Code:

```
package skyvity.belisini.Controller;

import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;import org.json.JSONArray;import org.json.JSONException;import org.json.JSONObject;import java.util.ArrayList;import java.util.List;importskyvity.belisini.Config.JSONParser;

public class ItemController {

//Listing Home
public  static JSONArray jsonArray= null;
public static ArrayList<String> Item = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> desc = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> price = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> seller = new ArrayList<String>();
public static ArrayList<String> picture = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void list_item(){
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    JSONParser jsonParser= new JSONParser();
jsonParser.request(JSONParser.base_url+"json",params);
    if(object!=null){
        Log.v("Proceed", "Succeed");
        Log.v(JSONParser.base_url+"json",params.toString());
    }
    else{
        Log.v("Proceed", "Not Succeed");
        object = jsonParser.request(JSONParser.base_url+"assets/test/item_list.php",params);
        Log.v(JSONParser.base_url+"assets/test/item_list.php",params.toString());
    }
    try {
        if(object.getJSONArray("data")==null){
            Log.v("not Failed in here","NULL JSON");
        }
        jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("data");
        Log.v("not Failed in here",jsonArray.toString());
        for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++){
            Log.v("notFailed here","Lol");
            JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Item.add(jsonObject.getString("nama_item"));
            desc.add(jsonObject.getString("description"));
            price.add(jsonObject.getString("price"));
            seller.add(jsonObject.getString("seller"));
            picture.add(jsonObject.getString("picture"));
        }
    }catch (JSONException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.v("LOL" , e.toString());
    }
}
}
```

Well I curious with the Laravel Side web service. my current laravel returns

the Json return html

if it is to find log, may i know how to know it?

here are my jsons

```
{
status: 1,
message: "getting data",
data: [
{
nama_item: "Verix",
price: 1,
seller: "admin",
picture: "assets/img/sale/phpAF87.tmp"
},
{
nama_item: "Jasa ISP",
price: 500000,
seller: "wilztan",
picture: "assets/img/sale/php1D23.tmp"
},
{
nama_item: "Kevin William",
price: 1000000,
seller: "wilztan",
picture: "assets/img/sale/php1EC.tmp"
}
]
}
```

Comment: What problem are you facing exactly? What error are you getting?

Comment: @Abhishek well, my problem is i don't know how to start to parse laravel to android. currently i made laravel controller with `return response()->json($response);`. well it returns as json in browser. but when it comes to  android it returns json parse error in <doctype

Comment: This is nothing to do with laravel. Your Android code should only know what it is getting (read JSON). So can you please post a sample JSON you are sending to your Android code?

Comment: Moreover, I would suggest you should use postman, if you are not already using it. https://www.getpostman.com/

Comment: @Abhishek here is my code in Browser `{
status: 1,
message: "getting data",
data: [
{
nama_item: "Verix",
price: 1,
seller: "admin",
picture: "assets/img/sale/phpAF87.tmp"
},
{
nama_item: "Jasa ISP",
price: 500000,
seller: "wilztan",
picture: "assets/img/sale/php1D23.tmp"
},
{
nama_item: "Kevin William",
price: 1000000,
seller: "wilztan",
picture: "assets/img/sale/php1EC.tmp"
}
]
}` i've tried to use Postman but it returns as true json :/

Comment: what do you mean by 'true json'?

Comment: @Abhishek , well i mean it doesn't return as error or sth in Browser nor Postman

Comment: Ok. Which library are you using to parse the json?

Comment: Currently I am Using `JSONParser` one `compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'` @Abhishek